# Independent Identically Distributed Bernoulli Variables

Tags: probability

I am given the following problem;

If $X_1,...,X_n$ and $Y_1,...,Y_n$ are iid variables with Bernoulli distribution ($p = 1/2$), define $Z_i = X_i - Y_i$ and then find the probability mass function of $Z_1$ and the expected values of $(\sum Z_i)^2$ and $(\sum Z_i)^4$.

I recall that the probability mass function of a Bernoulli distribution with $p = 1/2$ would be given by $P(X_1 = x) = (1/2)^x\cdot(1/2)^{1-x} $, so we have the probability mass functions for $X_1$ and $Y_1$.

Then how to compute the pmf for $X_1 - Y_1$? And how to approach the expectations of the sums?

Answer (score 1):

$Z_i=\left\{\begin{array}{llc}1&\mbox{if }X_i=1 \land Y_i=0&\mbox{prob}=1/4\\
0&\mbox{if }(X_i=1 \land Y_i=1)\lor(X_i=0 \land Y_i=0)&\mbox{prob}=1/2\\
-1&\mbox{if }X_i=0 \land Y_i=1&\mbox{prob}=1/4\end{array}\right.$

I am sure you can work out the rest.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you. From this should I simply deduce what $P(X_1 - Y_1 = x)$ must be? I expected there to possibly be some rule along the lines of, $P(X_1 - Y_1 = x) = P(X_1 = x) - P(Y_1 = x)$ but I must assume such a statement is false.

Comment: Yeah that would be false, because $P(X_1=x) - P(Y_1=x)$ can be negative, while $P(X_1-Y_1=x)$ is not.